# Creating a WHERE IN clause using SQL JQUERY C# JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, sql, winforms

I am writing a large SQL statement, which has a large `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE
WHERE ID IN 
(
'C1',
'C2',
'C3',
'C4',
)
```

Is there a way I can wrap my list of values or a way to create the `WHERE ID IN` clause programatically?

My list of values are as follows:

```
C1
C2
C3
C4
C5
C6
C7
C8
C9
C10
C11
```

Comment: are the list of values stored ina column of table ?

Comment: And in what language does this `WHERE ID IN` clause would be implemented? `SQL`? `JQUERY`? `C#`? `JavaScript`? All?

Comment: I just want to create SQL syntax using a programming method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your list of values to be declared as ('alpha','beta','gamma') in your IN clause dynamic sql use something like.

`function retCol(arr) {
     return (arr.length ? "'" + arr.join("','") + "'" : "");
}`.

and then store the values in a variable 

`var myArray = new Array("alpha","beta","gamma");
var sortedVal = retCol(myArray);`. 

`var sqlString = "SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN ("+sortedVal+")`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will require Dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @query varchar(1000)
DECLARE @colList varchar(500)

SELECT @colList=COALESCE(@colList+',','') + columnName
FROM yourTable

SET @query = 'SELECT id FROM otherTable WHERE id IN ('+ @colList +')'

EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: Variable @colList contains comma seprated values of table column.

Answer (score -1):

We usually pass all the Ids as a concatenated `varchar`, like this:

```
declare @ids varchar(max) = 'C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9,C10,C11'
```

We then have a function to split the `varchar` into a `table`, and query is written like:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE
WHERE ID IN (select item from [dbo].[func_Split](@ids, ','))
```

We usually pass `@ids` as a parameter from code, so you can just create the string there. Or you create it in SQL.
See the function [func_Split here](http://www.biitb.com/index.php/t-sql-split-function/).

---

Can also be used as in mhasan's example, to avoid Dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @colList varchar(max)

SELECT @colList=COALESCE(@colList+',','') + columnName
FROM yourTable

SELECT ID FROM TABLE
WHERE ID IN (select item from [dbo].[func_Split](@colList, ','))
```